# Adding WPF UserControl to WPF Window in code

Tags: wpf, user-controls

is there a way to add a user control to a WPF Window created in code? I cant find a Children property in the Window Class. In xaml It would look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:MyUserControls="clr-namespace:MyUserControls" 
        Title="" Height="Auto" Width="550" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <MyUserControls:UC1 x:Name="uc1" />
</Window>
```

In code I tried something like this:

```
Window myWindow = new Window;
UC1 uc1 = new UC1;
myWindow.Children.Add(UC1);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is just pseudo code I wrote while typing the question. There is no Children property in the window class. That is my problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Children property is there if you have an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), i.e. a control which can have multiple children. A Window is a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx), i.e. it only has one "child", the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx). So the code should be:

```
myWindow.Content = UC1;
```